# Catching custom exception with Service Fabric remoting

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The following document details exception handling in remoting for Service Fabric (I use V2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#remoting-exception-handling

It has the following paragraph:

> All remote exceptions thrown by the service API are sent back to the
>   client as AggregateException. RemoteExceptions should be DataContract
>   serializable; if they are not, the proxy API throws ServiceException
>   with the serialization error in it.

I have made the following exception, in a .NET Core class library shared between the services:

```
[DataContract]
public class DuplicateEntityException : Exception
{
    public DuplicateEntityException(string message = "Duplicate entity.") : base(message) { }
}
```

I get the following message after throwing the exception in the called service:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The exception DuplicateEntityException was unhandled on the service and could not be serialized for transferring to the client.
```

If I just throw `Exception` it serializes correctly.

Any help in making my exception class DataContract serializable would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

All I had to do was:

```
[Serializable()]
public class DuplicateEntityException : Exception, ISerializable
{
    public DuplicateEntityException(string message = "Duplicate entity.") : base(message) { }

    public DuplicateEntityException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, are there any other details missing ? I still get serialization exceptions